# DataTable - how to achieve datacolumn expression (computed column) persistence?

Tags: c#, datatable, expression, calculated-columns, datacolumn

I have this `DataTable`

`FName LName Tag1 Tag2 Tag3 ... (not fixed, can be as many)`

What I want is

`FName LName TagAll`

So, I created a column `TagAll` of type `string` with expression as

```
var expression = string.Empty;
// ... other code
// In a loop for all tag columns
expression = expression + " + ',' + " + tagColumn;
// at the end of loop
 dtContact.Columns["Tag_All"].Expression = expression;
```

So, if I have 3 columns, the expression is like this

`"Tag1 + ',' + Tag2 + ',' + Tag3"`

For example the data is

```
FName LName    Tag1    Tag2    Tag3
Jeff  Atwood   test    tag     other
Matt  breeden  myTag   total   last
```

The resulting `DataTable` becomes like this

```
FName LName    Tag1    Tag2    Tag3   Tag_All
Jeff  Atwood   test    tag     other  test, tag, other 
Matt  breeden  myTag   total   last   myTag, total, last
```

It is fine till now, but now I would like to remove all these other `Tag(s)` column. I tried doing

`dtContact.Columns.RemoveAt(2)` but it throws `'System.ArgumentException'`

I am guessing it is because that column is used in a computed column expression, is that correct? Because when I remove column 0 or column 1. It works fine. So, is there a way that I could remove all these other `Tag(s)` column, given that they are used in a computed column expression? May be somehow make this column persistent? Though I searched for it on Google but couldn't find anything.

Also, like I said, it is not fixed that there would only be 2, or 3 or n number of these `Tag(s)` column, they are dynamic, and there can be just 1, `Tag1`, upto any... say `Tag88` or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this method:

```
//Usage
DataTable dtMod = GetModifiedTable( dt);

//Function to return modified data table
public DataTable GetModifiedTable(DataTable dt)
{
    var columnList = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                                 .Where(x => x.ColumnName.StartsWith("Tag"))
                                 .Select(x => x.ColumnName)
                                 .ToArray();

    DataTable dtNew = new DataTable();
    dtNew.Columns.Add("FName");
    dtNew.Columns.Add("LName");
    dtNew.Columns.Add("Tag_All");

    var results  = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => 
                       dtNew.LoadDataRow( 
                         new object[] { 
                                r.Field<string>("FName"),
                                r.Field<string>("LName"),
                                GetTagValues(r, columnList)

                              }, false
                        ));

    dtNew.Rows.Add(results.ToArray());

    return dtNew;
}

//Function to return csv values of given column list
public string GetTagValues(DataRow r, string[] columns )
{
    string csv = string.Empty;
    foreach(string column in columns)
    {
        csv += r[column].ToString() + ",";
    }
    return csv.Substring(0, csv.Length - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. You have to take another approach.

Add the TAG_ALL column but not as a computed column. For each row in the DataTable, go through all the TagX columns adding them up, and then assign the value to the Tag_All column. Repeat for each row. When finished, you can now delete the TagX columns.

Depending on the number of rows, this can actually be quite fast.

However, I'd question whether this is a good idea. If you are databinding the DataTable to some grid, then all you need do it not bind the TagX columns, or tell the Grid to make those columns invisible.

Answer (score 0):

*While handling huge data inside a datatable (about 500000 rows), looping over rows is taking time (even with `dt.AsEnumerable().Select()` method). I was searching for a faster method until i found the following workaround:*

1. Clone the datatable *(only structure)* to a new table
2. Loop over columns and remove expression *(set to "")*, or just remove the expression for a specific `Datacolumn`
3. Merge the new datatable with the old one.

Now you can delete the original column without affecting the computed column.

*Example:*

```
//assign expression
var expression = string.Empty;
expression = expression + " + ',' + " + tagColumn;
dtContact.Columns["Tag_All"].Expression = expression;

//Clone datatable structure
DataTable dtNew = dtContact.Clone();

//Remove expression from a specific column
dtNew.Columns["Tag_All"].Expression = "";

//Merge data with the new Table
dtNew.Merge(dtContact);
dtContact.Dispose();

//Now you can remove the column used within the expression
dtNew.Columns.RemoveAt(2);
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out this code:

```
private void creatable()
{
   dt.Columns.Add("FName");
   dt.Columns.Add("LName");
   dt.Columns.Add("Tag1");
   dt.Columns.Add("Tag2");
   dt.Columns.Add("Tag3");
   dt.Columns.Add("Tag_All");
}
private void removeColumn()
{
        string temp = null;
        List<string> colToRemove = new List<string>();
        int colcount = dt.Columns.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i <colcount ;i++ )
        {
            temp = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
            if (temp == "Tag1" || temp == "Tag2" || temp == "Tag3")
            {
                colToRemove.Add(temp);
            }
            temp = null;

        }
        foreach (string item in colToRemove)
        {
            dt.Columns.Remove(item);
        }
    }
```

It's working as per your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but I think you didn't read the whole question. I said it is not fixed that I would only have 2 or 3 columns, it could be dynamic.